# How to simplify the derived class of boost::static_vistor

Tags: c++, boost

```
template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  T operator()(int& i) const {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(i);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }

  T operator()(double& d) const {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(d);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }

  // ...
};
```

As you can see, for each different type, the implementation code for `operator()` is exactly same. Is there a practical way that we can simplify the code?

Thank you

// Updated based on the comments //

```
template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  T operator()(T& i) const {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(i);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }
};
```

Then the compiler(G++) will generate tons of [errors](http://codepad.org/6meceU3e).

///// Updated 2 based on comments from iammilind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::variant<int, double, string> VarIntDoubleString;

// T is the result_type
template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  template<typename U>
  T operator()(U& i) const {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(i);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  map<string, VarIntDoubleString> mapValuesThree;

  // store & retrieve char
  mapValuesThree["char_fieldI"] = VarIntDoubleString('c');
  char fieldI = boost::apply_visitor(ClassVariantVisitor<char>(), mapValuesThree["char_fieldI"]);
  cout << "fieldI: " << fieldI << endl;
}


~/Documents/C++/boost $ g++ -o p192f4 p192f4.cpp -Wall
~/Documents/C++/boost $ ./p192f4
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
aborted
~/Documents/C++/boost $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
```

To iammilind:
  As you can see, the compiler doesn't generate any errors or warning during the compilation time.

// Updated 3 based on comments from Konstantin Oznobihin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, double, string> VarIntDoubleString;

  template <class U>
  typename boost::enable_if<
    typename boost::mpl::contains<VarIntDoubleString, U>::type, T>::type operator()(U &v) const 
  {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(v);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  map<string, ClassVariantVisitor::VarIntDoubleString> mapValuesThree;

  // store & retrieve double
  mapValuesThree["double_fieldJ"] = ClassVariantVisitor<double>::VarIntDoubleString(2.3456);
  double fieldJ = boost::apply_visitor(ClassVariantVisitor<double>(), mapValuesThree["double_fieldJ"]);
  cout << "fieldJ: " << fieldJ << endl;

}
```

I have no knowledge about boost::mpl and cannot make it work. Please refer to [errors](http://codepad.org/lOnHharO)
May you let me how I can correct the code so that I use your idea and make it work.
Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use a template?

Comment: I have addressed your comment in the updated post.

Comment: @q0987: your template is incorrect, you cannot reuse `T`, you have to declare the `operator()` template with a new parameter, like iammilind did. I would also criticize the idea of throwing a `char const*`. It's much cleaner to let the `boost::bad_lexical_cast` propagate here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. basically, you suggest that I rather should NOT catch the exception and let it propagate to upper level. Is that what you try to convey?

Comment: @q0987: yes. The whole point of exceptions is that you don't have to check each and every operation for error or success, but can implement a general error handling strategy much higher up the call stack. In most cases, exceptions should propagate to the top level freely. There are special cases, but when you find yourself doing a catch/rethrow then it probably means you should let it bubble up on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templatized operator() as suggested by iammilind but filter types with boost::mpl:

```
template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, double> source_types;

  template <class U>
  typename boost::enable_if<
    typename boost::mpl::contains<source_types, U>::type,
    T
  >::type operator()(U &v) const {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(v);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
If you have boost::variant you can use it's nested types sequence `types` instead of boost::mpl::vector and you don't need to define the variant inside ClassVariantVisitor, here is an updated solution based on your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::variant<int, double, string> VarIntDoubleString;

template<typename T>
class ClassVariantVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T>
{
public:
  template <class U>
  typename boost::enable_if<
    typename boost::mpl::contains<VarIntDoubleString::types, U>::type, T>::type operator()(U &v) const 
  {
    try
      {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(v);
      } 
    catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
        throw e.what();
      }
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  map<string, VarIntDoubleString> mapValuesThree;

  // store & retrieve double
  mapValuesThree["double_fieldJ"] = VarIntDoubleString(2.3456);
  double fieldJ = boost::apply_visitor(ClassVariantVisitor<double>(), mapValuesThree["double_fieldJ"]);
  cout << "fieldJ: " << fieldJ << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Konstantin Oznobihin, I have updated my OP. I need your further help in order to make it work for me. Thank you

Comment: @q0987: see my edits, mpl::vector is not a substitute for variant, it was just a container for types allowed in the visitor, but if you have variant you don't need additional containers.

Answer (score 2):

Templatize the `operator()`:

```
template<typename U>
T operator()(U& i) const {
  try
  {
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(i);
  } 
  catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
  {
    throw e.what();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. If you implement in this way, you will lose the benefit of compiler time checking. Simply storing a 'char' type into the variant and compiler will not complain during the compilation time but will fail during run-time.

Comment: @q0987: you can restrict U to be one of allowed types using boost::mpl and enable_if, see my answer for a sample implmentation.

Comment: @q0987, I don't understand your concern. This will definitely do compile time checking. If you want to avoid few types (like `char`, then simply overload them keep them `private` & unimplemented).

Comment: @q0987: your remark does not make sense. The `variant` itself already limit the list of types, all the visitor class need is being able to act on each of them, and the template provides the adequate catch them all operator. If you need specific treatment of one or two, then **do overload** the template with a specialized version **for those**.